# Cygwin: open a character device

Tags: cygwin

I need to open a kernel module created in Windows with a userland program
compiled in Cygwin; from Windows I can open it by using

```
CreateFile("\\\\.\\deviceName",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL)
```

but in Cygwin if I try to use the

```
open("//deviceName", O_RDWR);
```

nothing happens; I've tried to use "\DosDevices\deviceName", //deviceName,
//DosDevices/deviceName etc.... but I'm unable to open the device.

There is a way to do this in Cygwin or I must use the CreateFile in the
userland application?

EDIT:
FYI in the kernel module the link is created this way after calling correctly a IoCreateDevice(....)

```
#define DOS_DEVICE_NAME         L"\\DosDevices\\deviceName"
...
RtlInitUnicodeString( &ntWin32NameString, DOS_DEVICE_NAME );
ntStatus = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&ntWin32NameString, &ntUnicodeString );
....
```

EDIT2:
Using Sysinternals WinObj I can correctly see my device under
\GLOBAL?? with the symlink \Device\deviceName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems that I've been able to find it: it is specified under

```
"/proc/sys/DosDevices/Global/deviceName"
```

and can be opened with

```
fd = open("/proc/sys/DosDevices/Global/deviceName", O_RDWR);
```